# Auto Submit form not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, forms, jquery-mobile

I'm having a little issue and I'm not sure how to resolve it. I have a page that auto submits a form and the action of the form is to go to an external url. The form does not auto submit when it is first loaded but it does so if I refresh the page. What's going on here then?

My autosubmit javascript is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function()
   {
     document.subfrm.submit();
   }

</script>
```

and my form html is

```
<form name="subfrm" action="http://www.theexternalwebsite.com" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Continue with Payment">
```

I've probably done something really stupid, my excuse is I'm stressed and have to many looming deadlines. Cheers!

Comment: Why are you trying to submit a form when the page loads? To direct the user for the `action` URL ?

Comment: put the scrit at the end of the page

Comment: I'll try the above. Also zuul, yup, thats right. we have a merchant site that we use to process payments. I have other form elements but didn't want to include them here...

Comment: I think I found my answer...http://markdalgleish.com/2011/04/document-ready-for-jquery-mobile/

Answer (score 0):

right, cracked it. In my form prior to this one I put

```
data-ajax=false
```

so the next page is loaded as a normal http..then it did the redirect as expected!

Answer (score -1):

This works:

```
<html>
    <body onload="document.subfrm.submit()">
        <form name="subfrm" action="http://www.theexternalwebsite.com" 
                method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Continue with Payment">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bensg/1/